# Why is the Python interpreter not thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, gil

The GIL locks cores so that threads cannot run in parallel. Why is this the case?
There is little information about this online.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Thread safety is hard and they didn't design for it from the beginning. Making it thread safe now is even harder.

Answer (score 2):

In very basic terms the GIL stops memory corruption, without GIL it is possible that multiple threads would execute at once causing unpredictable outputs.

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe. (However, since the GIL exists, other features have grown to depend on the guarantees that it enforces.)

See the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

As you will see there are implementations do not use GIL such as Jython and IronPython.

There is also a very helpful article on [Wikipedia that deals with this topic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)

> A global interpreter lock (GIL) is a mutual-exclusion lock held by a programming language interpreter thread to avoid sharing code that is not thread-safe with other threads. In implementations with a GIL, there is always one GIL for each interpreter process.